# Using css can I apply different background-images property already present(without using jquery)

Tags: css, angular-material2

I have

```
<parentdiv class="a">
  <child1 class="b"></child1>
  <child2 class="b"></child2>
  <child3 class="b"></child3>
</parentdiv>
```

Using css can I apply different background-images property already present on class b on each individual child divs(I'll have fixed no. of child divs), thanks
[Link to refer my usecase](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/35b474899b3f766657fdba305e9ceda6)

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper _ngcontent-c1="" class="mat-stepper-horizontal 
ng-tns-c4-0" role="tablist">

<div class="mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container">

<div class="mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container">
<mat-step-header class="mat-horizontal-stepper-header mat-step-header ng-tns-c4-0"
role="tab" ng-reflect-icon="number" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-selected="true" 
ng-reflect-active="true" ng-reflect-optional="false" tabindex="0" 
id="mat-step-label-0-0" aria-controls="mat-step-content-0-0" aria-selected="true">
<div class="mat-step-header-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLElement]"></div>
<div ng-reflect-ng-switch="number" class="mat-step-icon">
<span>1</span>
</div>
<div class="mat-step-label mat-step-label-active mat-step-label-selected"></div>
</mat-step-header>

<mat-step-header class="mat-horizontal-stepper-header mat-step-header ng-tns-c4-0"
role="tab" ng-reflect-icon="number" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-selected="true" 
ng-reflect-active="true" ng-reflect-optional="false" tabindex="0" 
id="mat-step-label-0-0" aria-controls="mat-step-content-0-0" aria-selected="true">
<div class="mat-step-header-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLElement]"></div>
<div ng-reflect-ng-switch="number" class="mat-step-icon">
<span>2</span>
</div>
<div class="mat-step-label mat-step-label-active mat-step-label-selected"></div>
</mat-step-header>

<mat-step-header class="mat-horizontal-stepper-header mat-step-header ng-tns-c4-0"
role="tab" ng-reflect-icon="number" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-selected="true" 
ng-reflect-active="true" ng-reflect-optional="false" tabindex="0" 
id="mat-step-label-0-0" aria-controls="mat-step-content-0-0" aria-selected="true">
<div class="mat-step-header-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLElement]"></div>
<div ng-reflect-ng-switch="number" class="mat-step-icon">
<span>2</span>
</div>
<div class="mat-step-label mat-step-label-active mat-step-label-selected"></div>
</mat-step-header>

</div>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

This is a Stepper module in Angular material2 and my objective is to set different individual background-images for each of the
three mat-step-icon(12,23,34)Line nos. classes present in each  using css3 properties(mat-step-icon class
which has backgound-image property which I need to override)

What i tried
I had give backgound-image in mat-step-icon class but it will get applied for all the mat-step-icon classes , is there a way so that for each of the mat-step-icon different background-image property can be applied

Comment: Can you change the filename of your Gist to be `.html`?

Comment: Hi Edric please help me in how can I change it to html I mean you want in js fiddle or something,thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I just like syntax highlighting on Gist... (you should post your code on this question instead)

Comment: oh ok sure i'll try to do it and update one more link,thanks

Comment: If you try to inherit from a sibling, that is not possible with CSS.

Comment: Hi @LGSon I want to set the background-image property of child div classes, please refer tot he link , thnaks

Comment: Hi @Edric  https://jsfiddle.net/7ockvqtq/ . Info(This is a Stepper module in Angular material2 and my objective is to set different individual background-images for each of the
three mat-step-icon(16,27,38)Line nos. classes present in each <mat-step-header> using css3 properties(mat-step-icon class
which has backgound-image property which I need to override))

Comment: First, post code within the question, second, what have you tried yourself? ... We would like to see also the CSS you are using for this. Also, have you checked how it works? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: Hi @LGSon I have posted the code here , I hadn't posted here earlier because people get annoyed seeing such code snippets :), thanks

Comment: Use `.mat-step-icon:nth-child(1)`, `.mat-step-icon:nth-child(2)`, `.mat-step-icon:nth-child(3)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159298/discussion-between-enthu-and-lgson).

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/3x2cp6rw/

Comment: I tried it out but in my code at all the three classes it takes up .mat-step-icon:nth-child(2) . class

Comment: Yes, it does, sorry, my mistake, it is the `<mat-step-header>` that is the equivalent for the `b` in the fiddle, so in your code it should be `.mat-step-header:nth-child(1) .mat-step-icon { background-image: url(...) }` and so on

Comment: @LGSon Thanks alot it is working I would have thought of it earlier , it is working taking odd nos. 1,3,5 , could you please enlighten me up and why it was only accepting nth-child(2) , I have some more queries regarding this please help me ,I will mark the it right if you give it as answer, thankyou very much

Comment: Why `nth-child(2)` worked, is that it is the 2nd element/sibling in the `<mat-step-header>` parent, where `mat-ripple` is the 1st and `mat-step-label` the 3rd.

Comment: Posted an answer for you

Comment: Thankyou very much , have some more queries :), thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target an element with the same class, one can in this case use the `nth-child()` selector.

The `nth-child()` is a *sibling* selector, so in your pseudo code it will look like this

```
.b:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url( path1);
}
.b:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url( path2);
}
```

But in your production code, it is not the `.mat-step-icon` class/element itself that we need to target with the `nth-child` selector, it is its parent, like this

```
.mat-step-header:nth-child(1) .mat-step-icon {
  background-image: url( path1);
}
.mat-step-header:nth-child(2) .mat-step-icon {
  background-image: url( path2);
}
```